# Angular loading bar for multiple ng-app in one page

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using angular loading bar. But I am not able to find a way to use it if a page has multiple ng-app.

http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/

https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar

Currently I am only able to add dependency to a single app like this

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angular-loading-bar'])
```

Is there a way to make it works for multiple ng-app in a single page

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - **Dependency Injection** - Meaning no. 
Angular is very strong with DI so it won't let you use the same module on multiple controllers, you will have to use a different module for every controller.

*This is not a smart approach either, as you are using the same code over numerous controllers making yourself a duplicate and non maintainable code.*

**Soultion:**

If you want to use the same module, do not use:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angular-loading-bar'])
```

In all of your controllers respectively, 
Choose a main controller that will contain your:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angular-loading-bar'])
```

In the other controllers use:

```
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp");
    myApp .controller
```

**This way you are avoiding the dependency injection fault, as you are using the same module over couple of controllers.**

If you want to add a dependency to your module, do it like that in your main controller:

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['angular-loading-bar', 'ng-sanitize'])
```

This will affect all of the controllers that derive from your module.

Comment: Actually there is no parent app or controller. Every part of the page has different app and their own controller. So my question is how to make the angular loader work in this condition.

Comment: Just give your app different names, this will resolve the DI.  angular.module('myApp1', ['angular-loading-bar']) angular.module('myApp2', ['angular-loading-bar']) etc...

Comment: Actually my question is not about dependency. Its about loader, the loader will be present till the page loads but since there is multiple apps how will it detect whole page load.

Comment: You will have to use different module names for your app, because DI won't let you do it. Your question is not about it but DI come from the back door in this case. Angular does not allow multiple modules with the same dependency name in the same app.